# WCF: How to configure net.tcp traffic on port 80

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a WCF service that is configured to run for a high port number (e.g. 9000) on netTcpBinding. It all works, but only if the client can access data on that port. We've had a number of cases where corporate firewalls have not allowed us to connect on this port without a lot of pain.

Is there a way I can configure it to work on port 80 without affecting the web applications that are running on the server currently, so that most corporate environments don't need to change anything? I am aware of [.net tcp port sharing,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx) but this won't allow port 80 over net.tcp.

If it's not possible to configure net.tcp over port 80, are there any "best practices" for this kind of situation to minimize the firewall issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you could try port 8080 which is allowed in most firewalls. 
IIS 7.0 currently doesn't support sharing same port between different protocol binding.
So HTTP + TCP on same port won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and the heads up for using 8080. Theres no reason why we do use 9000, so we can change to that port.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you bind to a specific ip. usually, when binding WCF services, people use 0.0.0.0 to accept on any ip. If you do that on port 80 or not specify a port, it will override all existing configurations in IIS, effectively killing all running sites.

The only way to do this is to have a separate IP that you can use for the port 80 binding, that the other sites are not using to connect.

Comment: Our production server does have 4 IP addresses bound to it, so we could use an IP for the IIS site that hosts the WCF service. But, as far as I can make out, you can't bind a website in IIS to use net.tcp on port X for ip address Y, can you?

Comment: I accidentally bound a WCF service to http://0.0.0.0 which caused the machine to route all traffic that was intended for IIS to our WCF service, so as far as I know, any binding you specify will override IIS listening for data.

Comment: So that's something you do in the WCF config, rather than the IIS manager I assume?